# Getting the wrong value when I try and pass an argument by refference in MASM ([assembly][x86])

Tags: assembly, reference, x86, masm

I'm trying to learn how to pass and access values by reference in MASM.

I wrote a simple program that will display `val1` and `val2` using the Irvine.inc library.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCall: DWORD

.data               ;date values
    array DWORD 100, 100, 200
    val1 DWORD 50
    val2 DWORD 6000
    charVal BYTE 'x', 0

.code               ;Code
main PROC
    
    mov eax, val1               ;this is a test to see if it works properly. 
    call WriteDec               ;writes eax in Decimal form to the console
    
    push OFFSET val1            ;push two values by reference onto the stack
    push OFFSET val2            
    call PrintNum

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

PrintNum PROC
    push ebp                    ;save ebp so we can go back to the program
    mov ebp, esp                ;esp should point to the top of the stack
    pushad                      ;why do we need to do this?
    mov eax, 0                  ;zero out eax because I though that might be the problem
    mov eax, [ebp+12]           ;this should move what is in the value of ebp+12 into eax (val1)
    call WriteDec               ;this writes what is in eax to the console
    mov eax, [ebp+8]            ;this should move what is in the value of ebp+8 into eax (val2)
    call WriteDec               ;this writes what is in eax to the console
    pop ebp                     ;get back to correct ebp section of the code
    popad                       ;needed to do this because pushad from before
    ret
PrintNum ENDP
End main
```

The program isn't writing out the value in the address. What am I doing wrong?

After taking into account what @Jester said. My code works with the added `mov eax, [eax]`.

I have now tried to do it again in a different test program and it works without `mov eax, [eax]`. What is the difference here?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCall: DWORD

.data               ;date values
    val1 DWORD 200
    val2 DWORD 100

.code               ;Code
main PROC
    push val1       ;needed to add the offset not the value
    push val2       ;needed to add the offset not the value
    call PrintVars


    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

PrintVars PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+12]   ;mov address of val1 into eax
    ;mov eax, [eax]     ;use address to get actual value
    call WriteDec       ;write the dec to the console
    call Crlf           ;carage return
    mov eax, [ebp+8]    ;mov address of val2 into eax
    ;mov eax, [eax]     ;deference address to actual value
    call WriteDec       ;write the dec to console
    call Crlf           ;carage return
    pop ebp
    ret
PrintVars ENDP
End main
```

Comment: You are missing a level of indirection. `mov eax, [ebp+12]` is just loading the address you put on the stack. You want the value, so you need to do `mov eax, [eax]` afterwards. You can remove the `pushad`/`popad` those are not needed. You can also remove the `mov eax, 0` as that is  not the problem :)

Comment: Why isn't our teacher explaining this? I have been on this for days now.

Comment: @Jester Ok, so I'm going to loose my mind. I did what you said in my original code. It worked. Now I rewrote it in another test project and it works without `mov eax, [eax]`. What on earth is going on?

Comment: You must have made some other change, for example omitted the `OFFSET` keyword so you actually pass by value not reference.

Comment: You are right. I must be tried. It's only 11 am.

Comment: Instead of putting the answer in the question, I recommend self answering your own question with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using **M**ASM, an instruction like `push OFFSET val1` pushes the address of the label *val1*, and an instruction like `push val1` pushes the value that is stored at the address *val1*.

*In **N**ASM, an instruction like `push val1` would push the address of the label *val1*, and an instruction like `push dword [val1]` would push the value that is stored at the address *val1*.*

### Program 1

In the first program, where you pushed the address of the label, your *PrintNum* proc will have to dereference since you want the value that is stored at the address so you can print it.

```
  push OFFSET val1    ; Push two values by reference onto the stack
  push OFFSET val2            
  call PrintNum

  ...

PrintNum PROC
  mov  eax, [esp+8]   ; OFFSET val1
  mov  eax, [eax]     ; Get value stored at val1
  call WriteDec
  mov  eax, [esp+4]   ; OFFSET val2
  mov  eax, [eax]     ; Get value stored at val2
  call WriteDec
  ret
```

### Program 2

In the second program, where you pushed the value that is stored at the address of the label, your *PrintVars* proc no longer needs to dereference as you already have the value itself.

```
  push val1           ; Push two values by value onto the stack
  push val2            
  call PrintVars

  ...

PrintVars PROC
  mov  eax, [esp+8]   ; Value stored at val1
  call WriteDec
  mov  eax, [esp+4]   ; Value stored at val2
  call WriteDec
  ret
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in my `mov eax, [ebx+12]`. It isn't enough to deference in one line. Another deference must accure. `mov eax, [eax]`. The completed code is below.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCall: DWORD

.data               ;date values
    val1 DWORD 200
    val2 DWORD 100

.code               ;Code
main PROC
    push OFFSET val1       ;needed to add the offset not the value
    push OFFSET val2       ;needed to add the offset not the value
    call PrintVars


    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

PrintVars PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+12]   ;mov address of val1 into eax
    mov eax, [eax]     ;use address to get actual value
    call WriteDec       ;write the dec to the console
    call Crlf           ;carage return
    mov eax, [ebp+8]    ;mov address of val2 into eax
    mov eax, [eax]     ;deference address to actual value
    call WriteDec       ;write the dec to console
    call Crlf           ;carage return
    pop ebp
    ret
PrintVars ENDP
End main
```

Comment: Your 'completed code' is wrong again! See if my answer helps to understand.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I had copy pasted the wrong code. The code in my IDE was right but I pasted what I posted on here. Thanks for your answer too.